# Factorisation of algebric expression

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, computational-mathematics

If $a+b+c+d+e=0$ than factorise $a^3+b^3 +c^3+ d^3 +e^3$.   . I know that if $a+b+c+d=0$ than $a^3+b^3 +c^3+ d^3 = 3(a+b)(a+c)(a+d)$. Similarly can we say something about $a^3+b^3 +c^3+ d^3 +e^3$.
It will be a great help if someone can solve it or give some hint about it.

Comment: What's to solve?  $(a+b+c+d+e)^3 = 0^3 = 0$.  You don't need to do *anything* more.

Comment: Sorry I need to solve $a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+e^3$

Answer (score 1):

We then have
$$
a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3+e^3=
- 3((b + c + d)^2a + (b + c)(b + d)(c + d) + (c + d + b)a^2).
$$

Comment: It looks suitable for me. Could you please tell me how did you get it Dietrich?

Comment: I substituted $e=-a-b-c-d$ and then regrouped like in the case with four cubes.